# Set converter on TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to calculate/change form of input between textbox to its bindable source. The way i trying to achive this, is with help of converters.

Converter:

```
    public class ParameterConverter : IValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return string.Empty;

        string originalParameValue = value.ToString();

        string fixedParameterValue = string.Format("@_{0}", originalParameValue);

        return fixedParameterValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <converters:ParameterConverter x:Key="parameterConverter"  />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ParameterA, Converter={StaticResource parameterConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is, that converter is functioning only once. Is it approach correct (i mean with converter) or there are another approaches ?

Comment: In this case [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) instead of Converter should be enough.

Comment: Looks like the source is updating the textbox only once (I mean the ParameterA's property value is not setted many times)

Comment: Where is `ParameterA` coming from? Is the UI being notified when it changes?

Comment: ParameterA is a property bindable to the textbox as shown at the above. Actually this property within code behind.

Comment: @Jviaches could u post your code behind in which you have the ParameterA property?

Comment: @Jviaches You either need to make the property in the code behind a `DependencyProperty` or implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to inform the UI when the property changes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the binding Mode is not two way, and did your property fire property changed.

Comment: Mode=TwoWay is not helping

Answer (score 0):

Does your data context implement INotifyPropertyChanged and is PropertyChanged being called whenever ParameterA is changed? It seems as if nobody is notifying the textbox that it needs to update its contents.